# What is a good algorithm to manipulate a lot of DateTime Records?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, algorithm, datetime

I have a SQL server table in form of

```
DATA,Startdatetime,Enddatetime
```

And it means that my sensor has an state of DATA in duration of `Startdatetime` and `Enddatetime`. I have lots of these data. So is there any algorithm or class or a way to query (in c# level or SQL level) that I can ask in a specific time what was my sensor state?

Comment: Make startdatetime the primary index to reduce time to retrieve data.

Comment: You should investigate alternate technologies.  Consider a stream processor, such as Apache Storm or Azure Stream Analytics.  Also consider a time-series database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL if you want the data for instance for `'2015-08-16 17:33:45'`

```
select data
from your_table
where '2015-08-16 17:33:45' between Startdatetime and Enddatetime
```

Comment: I am looking for an optimized way, your answer is correct. But suppose that for a period of day you have 24*3600/30 queries! I want to query every 30 seconds.

Comment: And that is the fastest query I can think of. Add indexes to the datetime columns and it should return results in a few milliseconds, even if you have milions of records

Comment: Isn't a way like importing data into a dataset in C#, then processing them with LINQ or something else?

Comment: The fastest way to get data is in the DB level. And get only the data necessary. Don't load all data into your app and fiilter it later. That takes way too long and needs a lot of memory

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the other answer here with your additional requirement of being able to do this over multiple points in time:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME2(0) = '2015-01-01',
    @endDate DATETIME2(0) = '2016-01-01',
    @intervals INT;

SELECT @intervals = 2 * DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @startDate, @endDate) + 1;

WITH pointsInTime AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, 30*(n-1), @startDate) AS p
    FROM dbo.[Numbers] AS [n]
    WHERE n < @intervals
)
SELECT p.p, t.DATA
FROM [pointsInTime] AS p
LEFT JOIN dbo.yourTable AS t
    ON p.p >= StartDateTime AND p.p <= EndDateTime;
```

Where `dbo.Numbers` is a bog standard tally table. The idea here is to generate the 30 second intervals using the tally table and then use that to drive the select of your data. Note - I used a left join because I don't know if there's a guarantee of there being data for a given data point. If you don't need such times to show up in your result set, you can safely change it to an inner join.